# $observe element's class-name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a UI.Bootstrap drowndown:

```
<li class="dropdown hello" id="contentMenu" watch-content>
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" >
            Content options
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
            <li ng-repeat="option in options">
              <a><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="contentChoices"  checklist-value="option.id" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"> {{option.slug}} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

when this is clicked, it adds a class of `open` to the `li.dropdown.hello`

I am trying to watch for when the class `open` is added but it's not working.

```
.directive('watchContent', function ($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

    //     console.log(attrs.class)


        // attrs.$observe("class", function(value){
        //     console.log('change !');
        //     if(value.indexOf("open") > -1){
        //         alert("yes")
        //     }
        // })
    //     scope.$watch(function() {return attrs.class; }, function(newValue, oldValue, scope){
    //         console.log('change !');
    //         console.log(newValue)
    //         console.log(oldValue)
    //         console.log(scope)
    //         console.log(attrs.class)
    //         // debugger;
    //         if (elem.hasClass('open')) {
    //           console.log('YEs')
    //         } else {
    //           console.log('no')
    //         }
    //     });
      scope.$watch(function () {
          return elem[0].className;
      }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue === oldValue) { return; }
          alert(newValue);
      });
      scope.$apply()
    }
};
})
```

Comment: Not sure, but I guess you need to add `class` to directive's scope. Add this to your directive:  `scope: {class: '='}`

Comment: Docs for [$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) says: `Observes an interpolated attribute.`

Comment: I get no error and nothing showing in console or an alert when the class changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking too deep into why, it is a fact that `attrs` does not handle the `class` attribute as expected.

You can watch the elements `className` instead:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return elem[0].className;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) { return; }
    alert(newValue);
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/x3wbK/)**.

Comment: Cool, will give this a try tonight and get back to you!

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy: Did you try the solution above ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: thanks for following up. I tried it and didn't work precisely. It only triggered once and that was all. Didn't trigger again on class change. And it didn't trigger right away, only until I clicked something else afterwards

Comment: It is probably because the change to the element's class happens outside of the Angular context. In that case, you need to let Angular knos something happened (e.g. by calling `$scope.$apply()`).

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I will have to try next. I will update you once I visit that tonight

Comment: Any luck with that yet ?

Comment: Yeah and got this: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: Of course yoh get this error. What is that `$scope.$apply()` for ? (That's definitely not in my code.)

Comment: but you suggested in the comments that i need to let angular know by added $scope.apply()

Comment: No, I meant you should add `$scope.$apply()` where you change the class, not where you $watch for the change. How does the 'open' class get added ? It would be easier btw, if you created a fiddle or plunkr...

Comment: Added here, it's part of the bootstrap angularjs lib: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js

Comment: It seems to work fine for me (without the `scope.$apply()`): http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/EbCxr/

Comment: Will try it today, tomorrow

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy: LOL ! It was this lifetime after all :D

Comment: Yeah, I needed it for some other things and revisited this question. Awesome on you man!